# AngularJS 1.4 migration - ngOptions: Has track by broken object equality checks?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

I'm hoping you guys could help me shed some light on an issue I have been facing since we moved from Angular 1.3 to Angular 1.4.

I have created a supporting [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hqhw82n2/) demo which demonstartes this

### Explanation

I have a controller with a list of two `MyElement` instances, which a user can select with a `<select>`.

There is also a button which compares (`===`) the selected `MyElement` with the first element from the list. The result of this comparison is logged to the console.

The `<select>` uses a `track by element.id` to distinguish between `MyElement`-instances.

What seems odd is that the selected item is *never* equal to the first element of the list (even when the first element is selected). The object that is bound to `ctrl.selectedElement` is a different object, but with the same properties:

```
NO!
Object {id: 1, description: "First"}
MyElement {id: 1, description: "First"}
```

When I remove the `track by element.id` **or** go back to Angular 1.3 this behavior disappears (both elements are strictly equal, as I would expect them to be).

### Question

Is this a bug? Is this related to [fix(ngOptions)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef) but I am somehow missing the implications? What is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think in Angular 1.4 the `select` will transform the value into a String and fails if it compares it by **identity** to a number.

Comment: Is what is "passed to" `ng-model` also affected by this? Because that is where the issue lies. The thing that is "passed to" `ng-model` (and bound to my model) seems to be a new object that Angular created...

Comment: the good news is that it works without track by. The bad news is that I don't know why. Please also look at: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564

Comment: @sirrocco: the Jsfiddle doesn't use select as, so that can't be it, right?

Comment: @sirrocco I did some digging and may have found out why this is occurring. Check out the latest edit on my answer if you are curious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default equality operator in JavaScript for Objects yields true when they refer to the same location in memory. The update must be altering the objects in a way which does not respect the previous statement. Check out the [migration docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration) to see if the change is documented. Though, I can see that `track by` is indeed creating a new object - this will be the crux of a falsy `===` check

---

Use `angular.equals` for this, instead of `===`. There are some specifics to this check, as stated in the [angular.equals docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals)...

> Two objects or values are considered equivalent if at least **one** of the
>   following is true:
>
> - Both objects or values pass === comparison.
> - Both objects or values are of the same type and all of their properties are equal by comparing them with angular.equals.
> - Both values are NaN. (In JavaScript, NaN == NaN => false. But we consider two NaN as equal)
> - Both values represent the same regular expression (In JavaScript, /abc/ == /abc/ => false. But we consider two regular expressions as
>     equal when their textual representation matches).
>
> During a property comparison, properties of function type and
>   properties with names that begin with $ are ignored.
>
> Scope and DOMWindow objects are being compared only by identify (===).

```
// -- 'YES!'
console.log(angular.equals(this.selectedElement, this.elements[0]) ? 'YES!' : 'NO!');
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sduu16ad/) - updated demo

---

In an **attempt** to provide the best answer possible, I dug through the source of ngOptions in [v1.4.0](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/releases/tag/v1.4.0), and the following code for `track by` seems to be returning a new object, thus explaining all of the above.

```
// Get the value by which we are going to track the option
// if we have a trackFn then use that (passing scope and locals)
// otherwise just hash the given viewValue
var getTrackByValueFn = trackBy ?
    function(value, locals) { return trackByFn(scope, locals); } :
    function getHashOfValue(value) { return hashKey(value); };

var getTrackByValue = function(value, key) {
    return getTrackByValueFn(value, getLocals(value, key));
};

var locals = {}; // ---------- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ---------- new object
var getLocals = keyName ? function(value, key) {
    locals[keyName] = key;
    locals[valueName] = value;
    return locals;
} : function(value) {
    locals[valueName] = value;
    return locals;
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason this behavior has changed between Angular 1.3 and Angular 1.4? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: It's unfortunately hit or miss. The AngularJS docs are getting better, definitely better than previous years, but it's never straightforward to find. You might find yourself digging through source to really get the answer you're after. Could be more effort than it's worth. `angular.equals` seems like a viable solution, and it's provided for this type of usage. If you had used it from the beginning, you would not have noticed a break. It's a tough call to argue if you should have even seen it coming, I hear ya...

Comment: I linked to the [migration docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration), which seems to be our best available resource unless you start a serious hunt through the project changesets

Comment: @WernerdeGroot I edited my answer in attempt to provide the best answer possible, because I was curious myself. Please give it a look and let me know you felt this was helpful?

Comment: the `var locals = {};` doesn't seem to have anything to do with `track by`

Comment: @sirrocco how so? It's the return value in `getTrackByValue()`

Comment: Well it's the value used to track the object by. But that's not what's set on ngModel. (just look at locals - it's not the object that we find in ngModel)

Comment: It is, it's a copy. `locals` is a new object, copying the values from model. That's why the object function is `Object` and not `MyElement`

Comment: eh, I think I see what you're saying now. it's tricky to really find the issue. Either way it's more or less solved

Comment: Thank you for the thorough analysis!

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify` and then compare. I do not know that it is efficient to use or not.

```
var MyElement = function (id, description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
}

var MyController = function () {
    this.elements = [
        new MyElement(1, 'First'),
        new MyElement(2, 'Second')
    ];
};

MyController.prototype.isFirst = function (element) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedElement) === JSON.stringify(this.elements[0]) ? 'YES!' : 'NO!');  
    console.log(this.selectedElement);
    console.log(this.elements[0]);
};

angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', MyController);
```

Comment: Is there a reason this behavior has changed between Angular 1.3 and Angular 1.4? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: no i did not find document or anything. you may find solution by reading documents related to angular versions.